# asking funding while installing solc?

Tags: nodejs, solc, npm

asking for funding while installing solc cant we insatll by skiping it
npm install -g solc

changed 9 packages in 9s

1 package is looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to worry about this. Developer may be seeking for money to run their project. If you wish to fund them and support them then you can get details by running `npm fund`. This will list all the modules that are looking for fundings.

Think like if you are a developer and you have developed a valualble code many copanies like microsoft, google, meta are using. Such project are great and you may need money to keep running and working in such packages. So, you may also put the info as seeking for funding.

If you are really annoyed by this and do not want to see again then just run a code:

```
npm config set fund false --location=global
```

or for particular project:

```
npm config set fund false
```

- 

> Note: Looking funding does not mean you can not install without
> funding. It is just an information shown at the end of the
> installation process.

- 